# How to read e-mails in a local directory using Java?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I would like to create a java program that would get only the body/message of the mail, the mails are in .eml format and the mails are placed locally in my machine. The problem is when I try to look for ways to do this I'm still lead to use the Folder class which requires an active mail server. Now, my question is, is there any way I can extract the message part of an e-mail using the Javamail API without the need to connect to a server? Because doing the extraction of the message part of an e-mail without including its headers is nearly impossible with filestream.

Thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "local store provider" for JavaMail, but perhaps the simplest approach for you is to just use the MimeMessage that takes an InputStream.  Give it a (buffered) FileInputStream and it will parse the message for you.